# Merging python dictionaries differently

Tags: python-2.7, dictionary

I've python dictionaries within a list as follows

```
[{"item1": {"item2": "300", "item3" : "10"}},
{"item2": { "item4": "90", "item5": "400" }},
{"item5": {"item6": "16"}},
{"item3": {"item8": "ava", "item1" : "xxx","item5": "400"}}]
```

And I want to construct a dictionary as follows

```
{
 "item1" : {
   "item2": "300", 
   "item4": "90", 
   "item5": "400", 
   "item6": "16", 
   "item3" : "10", 
   "item8": "ava"
}
```

Traversing method:
1) Starting with item1 => is a dict with two keys. Add it to the new dict.
2) Then take the first key in the first dict and check if there is any dictionary with this key. item2 is again a dict with two keys and hence add those keys to the new dict.
3) Repeat the same for the keys in item2 until nothing is there to traverse down. While traversing if there is already traversed dict found skip that. For eg, in the last dict item3, we have item5 which is already traversed and added to new dict. So we can skip traversing this key.
4) Repeat step 2, for second key in item1 (Has to be repeated depends upon the number of keys in first dict.)

I know this is more complex. Is there any possibility to achieve this?

Comment: `I've python dictionaries as follows` - they are in a list?

Comment: @thefourtheye: Yes.. They are in list